# Find orthogonal projection on basis of V

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure what to do in part three of this question. To be clear, I know how to get the solution of part 2. I imagine part three is trivial?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there! ;-)

If your orthonormal vectors for the basis are $o_1, o_2, o_3$, put them into a matrix $O$ (by columns, first column is $o_1$, second is $o_2$, and third is $o_3$), and the projection of the vector $v$ onto $V$ is $OO^T v$.

Check out the wiki page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)

And also this video from a linear algebra course at MIT:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osh80YCg_GM&feature=PlayList&p=38823D6325151CED&index=16

Comment: Great. So, what does O^T mean?

Comment: @WilliamFalcon Transposed matrix O. It has $o_1,o_2,o_3$ as rows.

Answer (score 0):

You've found orthogonal basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ of $V$. So use Gram-Schmidt process again to find orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$, it will be $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$.Next write $w=(1,2,3,4)$ as:

$$av_1+b_2+cv_3+dv_4=(1,2,3,4)$$

The orthogonal projection which you're looking for is $av_1+b_2+cv_3$.